# ask about send image failed using telegram API?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

now i'm work with telegram API. i want send an image with this API but my code doesnt work, when i run it, i have a blank response.

here is my code :

```
<?php




$comment= $_POST['tag'];
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botMY_BOT_ID/sendPhoto';

try {
$curl_connection = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('chat_id'=>'chatid','photo' => "@"."maldini.jpg")));
//curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize("path/to/maldini.jpg"));
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Data are stored in $data
$data = curl_exec($curl_connection);

curl_close($curl_connection);
} catch(Exception $e) {
return $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

but, when i try send image with just html, i works perfectly. here is my html code :

```
        <form method="POST" action="https://api.telegram.org/botMY_BOT_ID/sendPhoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>
            <span>chat_id :</span>
            <input id="chat_id" type="text" name="chat_id" value="chat_id" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>caption :</span>
            <input id="caption" type="text" name="caption"/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>photo</span>
            <input id="photo" type="file" name="photo" />
        </label>      
         <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="sendPhoto" />
        </label>    
    </form>
```

whats wrong??? any help would be appreciate, thanks in advance :)

Comment: don't chain calls like that. curl doesn't ALWAYS return json, and since you feed that potentially not-json directly into a decode call, you'll never see what curl DID return. never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources. always assume failure, check failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise: `$res = curl_exec($ch); if($res === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`

Comment: Hi Marc, i have edit my code, but i still get nothing....

Comment: `print_r($data);` after curl execution  and see the result ... @IIMNURDIANSYAH

Answer (score 0):

just need to pass `chat_id` with the url, try this code

```
<?php 
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_id>/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chat_id ;

$post_fields = array('chat_id' => $chat_id,'photo'=> "/path/to/image.png");

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: hi manjeet :), i have change my code as yours, but i didnt get notice anything, just blank page. is it because my php version php 5.6 ?

Comment: hi manjeet :), i have change my code as yours, but i didnt get notice anything, just blank page. is it because my php version php 5.6 ?